# Assign textView's value to int, IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, int

I have a textView (tF1) that will be supplied with a numeric value by the user. I need to assign that to number to the int (n).

This is what I came up with:

```
#import "blabla.h"

int n;

....

[tF1 resignFirstResponder];
n = (int)[tF1 text];
NSLog(@"n is, %d",n);
```

My problem is that the int value comes out to be a vary large number, like 82296768, for a textview value of 4.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated! :)

***SOLVED***

changed line,
n = (int)[tF1 text];

to,
n = [[tF1 text] initValue];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSString` has a method `intValue` that you should be using:

```
n = [[tF1 text] intValue];
```

From the documentation for NSString, the other numeric values you can retrieve are:

```
– doubleValue
– floatValue
– intValue
– integerValue
– longLongValue
– boolValue
```

To invert this process, that is to add a numeric value as a string, you can use the `NSString` method `-stringWithFormat:`, e.g.

```
[tF1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", someIntValue]];
```

Comment: That is very error prone and incorrect. If the textfield contains an invalid number, 0 will be returned, thus causing the application to believe a valid number (0) was entered.

Comment: @Dylan: The OP specified that `tF1` has a numeric value, in which case this is the best method.

Comment: Actually, OP specified that `tf1` will have a numeric value *supplied by the user*. It is always best practice to validate user input and `NSNumberFormatter` will take care of the heavy lifting in this case.

Comment: @Dylan: I disagree. I test user input by overriding `UITextView` delegate method `– textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` in which case doing as I suggest is faster and completely robust.

Comment: Well im a high school student who has had no previous background on objective-c, so im sure if this is not the most correct way of doing this, I will learn that down the road but as for now, it works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using an `NSNumberFormatter` to get the numeric value. Take a look at the method `numberFromString:` in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000202-BCICBCFA).

Comment: Technically this will give the OP an `NSNumber` not an `int`.